# Pin with no driver - Kicad

Tags: power-supply, kicad, l293d

I'm new to Kicad and I'm having some problems using Eeschema. Every time I connect a power source to an IC pin, in this case the L293D, I get the following error:

```
ErrType(3):Pin connected to some other pins but no pin to drive it
```

I'm just connecting the IC's pin to a +9V power source icon. I'm using an external library that includes this H-Bridge. I can't see what I am missing.

Thanks in advanced.

Answer (score 3):

You need **Power Flag**.

Every time you add a symbol from *power* library you need to add a power flag.

From [documentation](http://docs.kicad-pcb.org/5.0.2/en/eeschema/eeschema.html#power-pins-and-power-flags):

> It is common to have an error or a warning on power pins, even though all seems normal. This happens because, in most designs, the power is provided by connectors that are not power sources (like regulator output, which is declared as Power out).

Read the whole part about power flags in the link above for more information. This question has been asked millions of times (for instance, [here](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/19338/erc-error-errtype3-pin-connected-to-some-others-pins-but-no-pin-to-drive-it)).

By the way, do you have a connector or some other stuff from where your +9 V are actually coming to the IC and other circuitry?

Comment: `do you have a connector [...]` - yes I do. What's the proper way to treat this case ?

Comment: @kellogs Then put Power Flag on your connectors power lines, i.e. on the tracks that come to the other circuitry.