# Can I continue to generate a netlist despite ERC errors?

Tags: pcb, pcb-design, kicad

I am a KICAD newbie and have stumbled upon a few problems. I have about 119 ErrType(2) warnings and one ErrType(3) warning all essentially saying that the wires are not properly connected to their components. This is true(?) for some cases:

[image]

However, i encounter the same problem even after "fixing" some of the issues.

[image]

Can I simply continue on to generate a netlist ignoring these "warnings" and will KICAD understand the connections between components? Or are these warnings severe and if so how should I fix them?

Answer (score 1):

The grid you set in EEschema is too fine.

Set it to 100mil (right click in empty space, grid.. 100mil) and then re-place the symbols (pick up with [M] and drop again). Usually the symbols that ship with the KiCAD libraries have pins on a 100mil grid. If you use these you don't need anything else.

Also to check if a device has been connected hover with the mouse over it, hit [G] and move the mouse. If the wires are connected they will 'rubberband' with the device when you move your mouse.
Hit [ESC] to abort the special move operation with 'rubberband' wires.

And running a netlist with unconnected tracks/devices is pointless as you need this to be 100% error free to be able to help you during layout.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't generate a netlist if you have errors in your schematic.  The netlist won't be able to connect all points, so when you go to make the PCB, your ratsnest won't show all the connections you need to make.

To be honest, I don't remember if KiCAD will even let you generate a netlist if there are errors.  I probably did try it at least once, but I also went back and fixed all the errors.  So, no idea if you can even do what you want to.  Even if you could, it would be a bad idea.

So, fix the errors.  This will also help you to make better components and schematics, its all good.  Its a nuisance when you want to get on with things (I want my PCB NOW, damnit) but the next time around it will go faster and you will appreciate how a correct netlist makes the PCB layout easier with the ratsnest.

A couple of common causes for Type 2 ERC errors:

1. No symbol names on pins in schematic components.  Most common on components created by the user.  All pins must have a signal name.  I've screwed those up before.
2. Pins on components that are left floating.  All pins need to go somewhere.  Even unused pins on an opamp need to go somewhere.
3. Wires that look connected, but aren't.

Type 3 ERC errors are caused by bad power connections.

[See this other EE Stackexchange question on how to fix that.](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/19338/erc-error-errtype3-pin-connected-to-some-others-pins-but-no-pin-to-drive-it)